# Accessing DFS network shares via VPN

Tags: vpn, windows-server, dfs

I have DFS setup on my windows domain so users can access network shares via a drive mapped to `\\my.domain\shares`. Folders are stored on a WS2008 file server (path is `\\server01.my.domain\sharedata$`).
When accessing via VPN (SSL), users cannot get to the shares via `\\my.domain\shares`, but they're able to get to them via the UNC path `\\server01.my.domain\sharedata$`.
Stranger still, after accessing once to the shares via `\\server01.my.domain\sharedata$`, they are also able to access to the drive mapped to `\\my.domain\shares`.
I am using a Zyxel USG310 firewall with Secuextender SSL VPN client. The IPSec client (also called secuextender, a rebranded version of thegreenbow VPN client) works fine with both paths. Client settings seems to be the same.
Any setting comes to mind?

Comment: Is it specifically `\\server01` or is it `\\server01.my.domain`?

Comment: it's `\\server01.my.domain`, thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

By default, DFS referrals are sent using "short" (NetBIOS) names, e.g. `\\server01`, which external clients cannot resolve if the VPN client does not set the correct **'DNS Search Suffix'**. (The suffix tells the OS how to expand single-word hostnames to full domain names.)

You'll probably want to configure your DFS root server to send full domain name (FQDN) referrals instead, so that clients would be redirected to `\\server01.my.domain` which can always be resolved using DNS.

The full instructions can be found at https://support.microsoft.com/kb/244380/, but the summary is:

1. Remove all domain-based namespaces from your DFS root server.
2. Set the registry parameter:

   ```
   Set-DfsnServerConfiguration -ComputerName ABC -UseFqdn $true
   dfsutil server registry dfsdnsconfig set %COMPUTERNAME%
   reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dfs /v DfsDnsConfig /t REG_DWORD /d 1
   ```
3. Restart the `dfs` service.
4. Re-add all domain-based namespaces.